# Python: Mocking keyboard interrupt from code

Tags: python, opencv

I have some code which waits for a key press in another thread.

In addition, I catch mouse events, in which in some cases, I want to mock a keyboard key press, so the other thread "thinks" the user hit some key in the keyboard.

Is it possible to do it? Can you please share a code example?

NOTE:

Actually, I needed it for `cv2.waitKey(0)` in OpenCV.
I finally just use `cv2.waitKey(1)`, so my mouse changes are updated every millisecond anyway.

I am closing the thread and I'm sorry for bothering you, hoping that it could help to anyone else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def wait_for_input(callback=lambda x:x):
    callback(raw_input("Enter some Crap:"))

def mock_wait_for_input(callback=lambda x:x):
    while True:
        if random_time_condition_thing():
            callback("a") # mock hitting an A

def main_thread():
    def OnInput(what):
        print "GOT:",what
    th = threading.Thread(target=wait_for_input,args=[OnInput,])
    while True:
        if not th.is_alive():
            th = threading.Thread(target=wait_for_input,args=[OnInput,])
        print "Waiting..."
        time.sleep(1)
```

something like that I guess would be the easiest